# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0

Tags: python, json

looking for help from experts.

I would like to skip message when it contains `\xe0s` character or similar. My current skip message routine is working fine for standard json msg but in special cases like this with `\xe0s` program fails.

What must be changed in order to avoid failing ? My goal is, process only msg which contains `durationfld`, others just skip.

```
else:
    logging.info('Ignoring event in different format')
    return
```

**Message body being read where program get failed & restarted**

```
body=b'{"sender":"4603","message":"y se tykaji zpusobu, jak pozadat o preneseni \xe0s"}')'
```

**Part of the program**

```
.............
def convert_to_influx_format(message):
    time = message.annotations["iothub-enqueuedtime"]
    name = message.annotations["iothub-connection-device-id"]

    try:
        json_input = json.loads(message.body)
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        return

    if 'durationfld' in json_input:
        yellow = json_input["yellow"]
        msgid = json_input["msgid"]
        trigger = json_input["trigger"]
        durationfld = json_input["durationfld"]
        json_body = [
             {
               'measurement': name,
               'time': time,
               'fields': { "durationfld": durationfld, "yellow": yellow },
               'tags': { "trigger": trigger, "msgid": msgid }
             }
        ]
    else:
        logging.info('Ignoring event in different format')
        return

    return json_body

..................
class Receiver(MessagingHandler):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Receiver, self).__init__()

    def on_start(self, event):
        connect_influxdb()
        connect_iothub(event)
        logging.info("Setup complete")

    def on_message(self, event_received):
        logging.info("Event received: '{0}'".format(event_received.message))

        payload = convert_to_influx_format(event_received.message)

        if payload is not None:
            logging.info("Write points: {0}".format(payload))
            write_influxdb(payload)

    def on_connection_closing(self, event):
        logging.error("Connection closing - trying to reestablish connection")
        connect_iothub(event)

....

def main():
    try:
        Container(Receiver()).run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Error log**

```
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.013805723Z Traceback (most recent call last):
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.013872623Z   File "./readIotHubAmqpClient.py", line 178, in <module>
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.013966323Z     main()
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.013982623Z   File "./readIotHubAmqpClient.py", line 172, in main
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.014014222Z     Container(Receiver()).run()
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.014027022Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/proton/_reactor.py", line 184, in run
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.014074722Z     while self.process(): pass
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.014089822Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/proton/_reactor.py", line 241, in process
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.014120422Z     event.dispatch(handler)
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.014132922Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/proton/_events.py", line 165, in dispatch
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.014176722Z     self.dispatch(h, type)
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.014191222Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/proton/_events.py", line 165, in dispatch
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.014379122Z     self.dispatch(h, type)
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.014402722Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/proton/_events.py", line 162, in dispatch
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.014588722Z     _dispatch(handler, type.method, self)
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.014610322Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/proton/_events.py", line 123, in _dispatch
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.014652222Z     m(*args)
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.014713222Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/proton/_handlers.py", line 260, in on_delivery
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.014841522Z     self.on_message(event)
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.014862822Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/proton/_handlers.py", line 286, in on_message
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.014896422Z     _dispatch(self.delegate, 'on_message', event)
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.014937122Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/proton/_events.py", line 123, in _dispatch
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.014970122Z     m(*args)
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.014982422Z   File "./readIotHubAmqpClient.py", line 139, in on_message
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.015060022Z     payload = convert_to_influx_format(event_received.message)
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.015077922Z   File "./readIotHubAmqpClient.py", line 100, in convert_to_influx_format
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.015144321Z     json_input = json.loads(message.body)
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.015160421Z   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/json/__init__.py", line 343, in loads
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.015208121Z     s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')
[36mamqp         |[0m 2020-02-10T13:05:37.015233721Z UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 73: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: It looks like the JSON you are receiving has been badly encoded at the source. Consider to fix the problem there.

Comment: This type of byte `0xe0` if I'm not mistaken can be solved using `latin1` as decoding, but I don't know how to pass that as an argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try

```
json.loads(message.body.decode("utf-8"))
```

If that doesn't work then you could do

```
json.loads(message.body.decode("utf-8","ignore"))
```

Comment: UTF-8 is *already* being used to decode the non-UTF-8-encoded string; that's the problem.

Comment: Using `.decode("utf-8","ignore")` should encode the message and ignore the invalid characters

Answer (score 1):

Your input is in an ascii-compatible but non-utf-8 encoding. Things work out when everything is in ascii but as soon as the input is outside ascii it violently blows up, for good reason as you're feeding non-utf8 data to your decoder.

Find out what the encoding of the input *actually* is, and either decode it correctly, or fix whatever produces your data. I'd recommend checking what the ISO-8859 encoding is for the language the source generates, or what the Windows encoding / codepage is. Both are common culprits.

Comment: And this `... o preneseni \xe0s` -> that looks just like your regular bog standard default [Windows Latin 1 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).

Comment: Could be but I don't recognise the language so it could be any other ascii-compatible codepage e.g. Windows-1251 or 1257.